# Bicep Deployments to AppService Clears zip/Deployment Center Deployments

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep, azure-deployment

I am deploying an AppService environment via Bicep.  Everything is working well and is configured exactly as desired.

However, I have noticed that if I redeploy a Bicep template after I have deployed my AppService contents (via ZIP deployment using Azure DevOps), it completely clears all Deployment Center deployments, rendering an empty/default AppService.

Is there a way to stop this from happening?  I would prefer to retain the AppService deployed contents and keep them intact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out this issue, and it was a tricky one.  The problem was that the `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` environmental variable was not set. I was thinking that DevOps would be responsible for setting this, and it does.  However, when the Bicep deployment executes and this property is not part of the configured settings (and I do not merge them with existing values) it gets erased.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your bicep deployment mode is `incremental` and according to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-modes),

> In incremental mode, Resource Manager leaves **unchanged resources** that exist in the resource group but aren't specified in the template. Resources in the template **are added** to the resource group.

> When redeploying an existing resource in incremental mode, all properties are **reapplied**. The properties **aren't incrementally added**. A common misunderstanding is to think properties that aren't specified in the template are left unchanged. If you don't specify certain properties, Resource Manager interprets the deployment as **overwriting** those values. Properties that aren't included in the template are **reset** to the default values. Specify all non-default values for the resource, not just the ones you're updating. The resource definition in the template always contains the final state of the resource. It can't represent a partial update to an existing resource.

Please consider avoiding resetting your App Service by bicep deployment every time after deployment via zip,  if it is not required/necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the suggested answer, Alvin.  Is there not a way to tell Bicep/ARM "keep Deployment Center deployments intact during deployment"?  It would seem that this would be a common preference, especially when the deployment is updating properties for a website/slot.

Comment: Hi Mike, I am afraid not. We use bicep ARM template to create App Service resources and use pipeline to deploy applications. The deployment history in the App Service deployment center should be generated with each app deployments; however, bicep template deployment will reset the app as what is originally defined in the template. Per the current question, since you have succeeded creating the App Service resource via bicep, why you need to create this resource again? if you would change some configurations, you may consider other options like Azure CLI/Azure Power to modify the existing app.

Comment: Thank you for the discussion Alvin.  The way I see/understand Bicep is Infrastructure as Code (IaC) and is checked into source control.  In much the same way that deployments with code work, I view IaC the same way. For instance, let's say I want to update my SQL from 20 DTUs to 50.  In my mind, I edit my Bicep template for my Sql database and make the deployment. I also check in the change so that it's captured as the source record, just like code. All the resources that I have defined seem to work in this way, and as desired. It is only AppServices/Deployment Center that I have this problem.

Comment: Hi Mike, Appreciate your taking time to share the update. Unlike updating SQL DTUs, the history in Deployment Center no matter from `Azure DevOps` or `GitHub` are collected during each app deployment and I don't think a newly **created** App Service resource can include such app deployment history. I wonder if we could only update the SQL resource via bicep without updating the whole App Service resource. However, the current thread is under the subcommunity of `Azure DevOps`, would you share your scenario in the original post of a new thread with `App Service` and `Bicep` tag to get insights?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Alvin.  I had the azure-bicep tag there already, but did not have App Service (if I understood you correctly).  I have updated the tags to add this.  I am not sure about creating a new thread as I know some moderators are particular about this, but I did create an issue on Bicep's GitHub and maybe we can get some quality discussion there :) https://github.com/Azure/bicep-types-az/issues/2042